# Cannot start my Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, boot-issues

I'm trying to install my very first Raspberry Pi, but when I copy the NOOBS files to a 16 GB class 10 SD card, the lights (the red and the green) turn on but nothing shows on the screen. I already tried the 1, 2, 3 and 4 keys.

When I burn the image, available [**here**](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/), I got the `Kernel Panic: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179,2)` error. I already tried with 2 SD Cards with no change. Someone please can help me?

I used 7zip instead of WinRAR to unzip the NOOBS folders and now the device turns on but stays stuck in a colored screen.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend Raspbian over NOOBS -- the latter is I think actually more complicated since it is intended to allow you to install multiple operating systems.

> When I burn the image, available here, I got the Kernel Panic: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179,2) error.

This indicates the kernel did boot successfully, but the root filesystem on the second partition is unavailable.  This implies you might have copied only one partition from the image.  If you are using Windows some tools might do that.

If you are using Linux, OSX, or anything with `dd` available the methodology here is pretty foolproof.  If not, you should follow the [instructions for your operating instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) to the letter.  Currently it looks like Etcher is the recommended method; Win32DiskImager [should also work](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md).

> Someone please can help me?

There is not really anything to add to the official instructions linked above.

Comment: I've already tried Etcher and Win34DiskImager with the same result: `Kernel Panic: VFS : Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block (179,2) error.`

Answer (score 1):

If the lights are switched on and nothing shows on the screen I suspect the power supply may be too weak for your Raspberry board. Try a 2.5A power supply if possible.

See: [Raspberry Pi power requirements](https://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs)